# jQuery ajax autocomplete result box too small or with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am trying to complete jQuery UI autocomplete with ajax. I am using CI 3.1.5 and I get tiny result box or just number of results.

**This is my ajax:**

```
    $(".addClient").each(function() { 

        $(this).autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 2,       
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url:  "<?php echo  site_url('search');?>",
                type: "GET",
                data : { 'input_data' : request.term},
                success: function (data){
                    // console.log(data);
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(parsedData);
                    var result = [];
                    parsedData.forEach(function (value, index) {
                        result.push({label:value.name, value:index.name });
                    });

                    response(result);

                    },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log('error');
                }
                });
            },  
         });
        });
```

The results are in tiny box.

**I also tried this:**

```
$(".addClient").each(function() { 

        $(this).autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 2,       
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url:  "<?php echo  site_url('search');?>",
                type: "GET",
                data : { 'input_data' : request.term},
                success: function (data){
                    // console.log(data);
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(parsedData);
                    var result = [];
                    parsedData.forEach(function (value, index) {
                        result.push({label:value.name, value:index });
                    });

                    response(result);

                    },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log('error');
                }
                });
            },  
         });
        });
```

The box contains just the numbers of the objects.

**This is my jSon response:**

```
[{"NAME":"888"},{"NAME":"****"},{"NAME":"****"},{"NAME":"****"}]
```

**Edit:**

Thank you  Jaromanda X, you were right about this: NAME !== name!
Now I can see the suggestions in the autocomplete box, but when I choose one of the result in the input field I get:

```
[object Object]
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: what you are doing wrong is not explaining what the problem you have properly

Comment: If the data (the JSON-result) only contains numbers the error is not in the javascript, but rather in the data-fetcher. Therefore; check your php code that returns this result.

Comment: me a derp ... `NAME` !== `name`

Answer (score 0):

**JSON.parse** parses strings,
Therefore before parsing the data convert data into string and then parse it using **JSON.parse()**,

In order to convert to string rather use **JSON.stringify()**,

Also i am doubting if you are receiving **array** in the **promise** to function **forEach** loop, 
Check that, if it is not an array rather use **for(var obj in parsedData)**.

Also if you just want to directly push data to some array, you don't need to parse it if you are receiving array in the promise, 
directly execute

```
 var result = [];
                parsedData.forEach(function (value, index) {
                    result.push({label:value.name, value:index });
                });
```

Hope it helps !

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  Jaromanda X. This is the working code:

```
$(".addClient").each(function() { 

        $(this).autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 2,       
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url:  "<?php echo  site_url('search');?>",
                type: "GET",
                data : { 'input_data' : request.term},
                success: function (data){
                    // console.log(data);
                    var newData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log(newData);
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(parsedData);
                    var result = [];
                    parsedData.forEach(function (value) {
                        result.push({label:value.NAME, value:value.NAME });
                    });

                    response(result);

                    },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log('error');
                }
                });
            },  
         });
        });
```